# Not getting the Twitter Bootstrap template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am not getting the template shown when I view it in Firefox. I am just getting the "Hello World!". I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have built many sites in the past and it seems to work fine when I did the rest of them.

I am using PhpStorm to for my IDE and I am using Twitter Bootstrap, and the template isn't loading. It's just showing "Hello World!" in Firefox not the actual Twitter Bootsrap template.

[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DwVK.png)

Comment: You need to provide some code. I have no idea what the issue is without any examples.

Comment: Do you need to know the index.html? @JamesIves

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JamesIves I have added a image to help you.

Comment: There is no issue. Firefox just shows what is inside your html.